# Chakra UI responsive breakpoints does not work / Next13-Chakra

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

As I mentioned on title, Iam trying to give display none to nav links when its below lg otherwise it should be flex however it displays as block

Code...

```
<Flex width={'100%'} justifyContent={'space-between'} position={'sticky'} py={25} px={60}>
  <div>Logo</div>
  <Box width={'25%'} display={{ sm: 'none', md: 'none', lg: 'flex' }} flexDirection={'row'} justifyContent={'space-between'}>
    <Link href={'/'}>
      <Text fontSize={'2xl'}>Home</Text>
    </Link>
    <Link href={'/'}>
      <Text fontSize={'2xl'}>Home</Text>
    </Link>
    <Link href={'/'}>
      <Text fontSize={'2xl'}>Home</Text>
    </Link>
    <Link href={'/'}>
      <Text fontSize={'2xl'}>Home</Text>
    </Link>
  </Box>
  <Text display={{ base: 'none', lg: 'flex' }}>Lorem</Text>
  {/*<HamburgerIcon display={{ lg: 'none', base: 'flex' }} />*/}
</Flex>
```